# Why isn't parental controls blocking gameplay on days it should be blocked?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

Tl;dr: I'm looking for instructions for/how to fix the Xbox One parental controls setup to make that my kid require to ask for more screen time rather than setting a time limit / schedule allowed time.

---

I don't know how but all the members of my Microsoft Live Family were removed, so this Monday I added them again, and repeated the procedure to setup the parental control on the console including locking the creation of new accounts and setting up a guest key.

The setup for Monday, time limit 4 hours, from 4 pm to 8 pm, work fine.

The setup for yesterday (Tuesday, as well as other days of the week) was blocked the whole day and I was expecting that my kid send me a "more screen time" request but they were able to play without sending it.

How do I fix this?

The following screenshot was taken from the Screen Time Settings for my kid on the web.

[image: Device Limits and block schedule]

On the family there are other two child accounts with the exact same settings.
On the console my account is set to require a password / access key to join.

I already tried to fix this by changing from "Blocked" to "Max Schedule" but that didn't work either.

---

Progress

---

Today (Friday, September 6), while my kid is at school, it's working fine. Maybe there was a failure on the Microsoft side and someway it was fixed. Anyway, I will keep the console controls away my kid at study / rest time, at least until this works as expected for a while.

---

Today (Thursday, September 5) I found that the console had an account that it's not part of the family, also that the restrictions for no one signed-in was un restricted, then I figured out that the guest key wasn't in place so I added a guest key again, removed the account that isn't part of the family and changed the no one signed-in to restricted.

Maybe I forgot to sign-out and my kid used my account to change the settings.

I also found a similar recent post (August 30, 2019) on Microsoft Community

- [XBox One Screen Time restricitions no long work](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/xbox-one-screen-time-restricitions-no-long-work/bd3642fc-50d1-4033-8fd5-0a8a4a770e44?rtAction=1567710199230&tm=1567710210852)

No fix yet.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Could you please explain  as a comment/answer to [Looking for help to ask a parental control question about Xbox One](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13606/115285) why do you removed the links to related questions?

Comment: Those questions are not about the problem you're facing, so there's no reason to keep them.

Comment: You are right, they aren't exactly about the problem I'm asking but they are related and besides that I included them to show that I searched this site before asking as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 3):

4 things could have happened

1. They know your password and changed the settings
2. You could have not hit save so when it turned off it got deleted
3. They didn't play,they may have watched Youtube or something unless you blocked everything after 4 hrs
4. You have a good kid that didn't want to annoy you at work and went and did something else

Comment: After several months I still don't know what happened. I'm only sure that I have a good kid :)

Answer (score 1):

I just did this

In the Microsoft Family Live web page

1. Remove all the allowed schedule blocks and set all days as blocked

In the Xbox One console

1. Change my passkey
2. Delete and add new guest passkey
3. Double check that my account is Locked (requires the password to sign-in and to when switching from another account to my account)
4. Remove all the accounts (except mine)
5. Add the child accounts that are included in the family group

   At this point, before the account setup process starts it showed the notification that the account has to request permission. The permission was requested and I allowed 2 hours. As expect after this time, my kid reported that the end allowed time notification was shown.

So far, so good.

Later this night I will change my Microsoft account password and later this week I will "audit" the Xbox One console settings.